# dsym more info displays --

Tags: ios, crash, symbolicate

I am attempting to symbolicate a crash file but it appears xcode can not match the dsym file to the crash report.

Having done a bit of research I found the dsym file for my archive and when I go into getinfo and look at "more info:" it displays "--", I believe this should be showing the uuid and that this is the reason xcode cannot find it.

I'm guessing I need to change something in my build settings but don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the UUID of the dSYM by using the following command in the terminal:

```
dwarfdump --uuid YourDSYMPackage.app.dSYM
```